# How do I load antlr/index into ace worker js file?

Tags: javascript, antlr4, ace-editor

I am following the instruction given [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/ace-javascript-target.md) to integrate antlr4 with ace editor and I have trouble at the step `var antlr4 = require('antlr4/index');`. The author mentions that here we should use require for nodejs. However, ACE has another require that may cause problems. Thus he loaded another script for nodejs require and load `antlr4/index` with `require` in that script.
I tried that one, too. But it always cannot find the script. From the console of my browser, I can see the path it loads the script is:
`localhost:4200/./antlr4/index.js` and it fails to load it.

I am using Angular 7, and the structure of my project is as follows:

[image: stucture]

Also, when loading some local javascript file using importScripts, I always fails by giving the local path, however, giving URL from CDN will always work. But importScripts should support local file importing.

Where should I make changes and what else methods should I try?

Here are some of my code:

```
var ace_require = require; 
window.require = undefined;
var Honey = { 'requirePath': ['..'] };
//importScript{"require.js"}
//the script can't be imported through importSctipt so I pasted the 
//whole script file under...(not shown here)
var antlr4_require = window.require;   // antlr4_require：antlr using nodejs require；
window.require = require = ace_require;  // require：ace using its own require

var antlr4, LPMLNLexer, LPMLNParser;
try {
  window.require = antlr4_require;
  antlr4 = antlr4_require('antlr4/index');
  //the browser stuck here reporting error...
} finally {
  window.require = ace_require;
}
```

Comment: do you use webpack?

Comment: @auser no I didn't use webpack. I know another solution is to bundle antlr parser with the ace editor using webpack, but I see many open source code using this way to load antlr4, which works just fine. I really don't know what went wrong when using importScripts('localpath').

Comment: @auser now I am trying to use webpack and still have some problems, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125450/how-to-correctly-bundle-antlr4-generated-parsers-with-antlr4)

Comment: here is an example of antlr + ace working with webpak  https://github.com/nightwing/ace-antlr-example